# Get all records in SQL depending on user input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just learning SQL and came across a difficulty. My data table looks like this

**DBO DATA**

```
Id | Name | Surname | Title  | Location
----------------------------------------
1  | xxx  | abc     | def    | London
2  | xxx  | abc     | def    | Oslo
3  | xxx  | abc     | def    | New York
```

Now I want to get id, name, title and surname and I use query like this:

```
SELECT 
    Id, Name, Surname, Title 
FROM 
    DATA 
WHERE 
    Location = 'London' -- (this is user input)
```

But I get problem if the user inputs `All` or `World` or an empty string in `WHERE` clause, I want the query to return all rows. Is it possible to do this with writing another query to handle special scenarios like the above????

I am using ASP.net with a datasource like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Id], [Surname], [Title] FROM [DATA] WHERE [Location] = @Location)" >
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="Location" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

The input depends on the route path of URL `localhost:56789/People/London/`

The corresponding VB file is

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Request.PathInfo.Length = 0) Then

    Else
        Dim t = Request.PathInfo.Substring(1)
        Label1.Text = t
    End If
End Sub
```

I know I can do this application side but I am just curios if this is possible in query itself.

Comment: This should probably done application-side.

Comment: Where are you calling this SQL from? @Scotch is right, this should be done in your application, not in your database.

Comment: Also, never trust user input. This could lead to unwanted results: http://xkcd.com/327/ Prepared statements are usually the way to get around this.

Comment: I would do this in the DB.  It is a simple query and avoids mixing the data logic between multiple locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it in your query, try this:

```
SELECT 
    Id, Name, Surname, Tittle 
FROM 
    data 
WHERE 
    Location = <input> OR
    <input> in ('All', 'World', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add

```
or userInput in ('ALL','World','')
```

to your where clause, where userInput is the input from the user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a SQL Server instance here to confirm this sytax on but you could do something like;

```
SELECT 
    Id, Name, Surname, Tittle 
FROM 
    data 
WHERE 
   case 
      when <input> = 'All' then 1=1 
      when <input> = 'World' then 1=1
      else location = <input>
   end
```

How this works is it makes use the fact that each predicate (in effect where clause) has top evaluate to TRUE.  1=1 is always true so you will get all rows in the table.  and of course location =  will filter.

Comment: No, CASE's THEN clause can't have a boolean expression in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

What are you saying is that you want to apply some rules on what query to perform based on what the user enters. That is outside the scope of SQL.

It sounds like you are developing an application that takes input from the user. It's the job of that application to examine that input to determine what SQL query to run against the database. So check your input and do a `SELECT * FROM DATA` in the event your users enter nothing, "all" or "world".

Comment: I am using ASP.net with a datasource like this

Comment: Actually, in his case your query should be like `SELECT ID, NAME, SURNAME, TITLE FROM DATA`.

Comment: That's a matter of taste. Some people bother specifying columns explicitly merely to exclude a single column. Personally, I think that is pointless. Fetching the location column as well is unlikely to cause problems, but creates a shorter more readable query.

Comment: I know I can do this in application but wanted to know if it can be achieved in SQL query itself.

Comment: Like alecxe suggested you can apply an alternative condition, but IMHO it is a bad practice. You should not put that kind of logic into your queries, nor should you interpolate user input into your query strings.

Comment: @user2340086 As already mentioned here and in the comments on your answer, it really is bad practice. The reason is that it makes your code and database prone for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is a serious problem.